# Invoke-Sqlcmd not working after PowerShell 4 install

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, powershell-4.0

I installed PowerShell 4 over the weekend and ever since then, I get the error "The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function" when I try to run the Invoke-Sqlcmd commandlet.

This has been working just fine for months until PowerShell 4.

I have SQL 2012 SP1 installed with CU7. VS 2013 with .NET 4.5.1. As far as I can tell, I have all the latest everything that PowerShell requires.

How can I get this fixed?

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1

I asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/700663/invoke-sqlcmd-not-working-after-powershell-4-install) a couple days ago, but am not getting much traction there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the [SQL PowerShell module is imported](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231286.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that got the commandlet to load in the powershell window. I also had to re install PowerShellTools.msi from the SQL 2012SP1 feature pack.  Now to just figure out why TeamCity won't load it.

Comment: And I figure out that TeamCity 8.0 doesn't support powershell 4, but TC 8.1 will. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-33319